# How does the Copart car auction website (built with angular) send bid event data in a live auction?

Tags: angular, websocket, browser

I was trying to build a scraper for this website to get final bid data from live auctions for different cars. I was able to achieve this in a semi-automated way. While i was doing this I was curious how the bid updates came through the wire to update the highest bid on the ui.

This is what I found so far. Here is a screenshot of the network tab during one of these live auctions.

[image: Live Auction Image]

There are no visible websocket connections or anything like that, just lots of requests coming in with state flag images (flags of the state, or country, where the bidder is registered). They seem to line up with the most recent bid events. My question is, is the website sending data imbedded in the pngs, or are they doing this another way I'm not seeing. If they are sending it through pngs, is this a solution the devs came up with or is there something angular specific that allows you to this sort of thing.

Unfortunately, you need to sign up for a free account to view live auctions, if anyone cares to check it out for themselves. After you sign in, go to Auctions > Today's Auctions and choose any in progress auction.

I'm not an angular developer, so apologies, but I would like to know how this works. If any angular experts or anyone knows whats happening here can provide any info, that would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you downloaded any of those images and looked at the metadata? I imagine if these are the only requests, they are possibly encoding the bid amount into the metadata/EXIF of the image?

Comment: @crooksey I used a few online tools but couldn't find anything that would indicate some extra data. Unless this requires more in depth search, which i'm not familiar how to do.